# How can I encode an R vector of length 1 as a single value in json using the jsonlite R package?

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I am trying to encode R lists into json using the jsonlite package and the toJSON function. I have a simple item like:

```
list(op='abc')
```

I'd like that to become:

```
{
  "op" : "abc"
}
```

Instead, I get:

```
{
  "op" : ["abc"]
}
```

The API to which I am trying to feed this json chokes on the latter and requires the former.  Any suggestions on how to get the former behavior from jsonlite (or another R json package)?

Comment: Try `rjson` package. It is giving the former.

Comment: That works.  Any suggestions on how to get that behavior from the jsonlite package, which seems to have better performance?

Comment: I think it depends on your data. It seems that if your original data is a data frame, it will also gives the former. Can your data be converted to a data frame properly?

Comment: Unfortunatelly `rjson` has problems when saving to JSON file with diacritic characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `auto_unbox` argument does the trick with the `jsonlite` package:

```
toJSON(list(op='abc'),auto_unbox=TRUE)
```

yields:

```
{"op":"abc"}
```

Update: based on comment, this approach is probably safer, and an example of why:

```
> jsonlite::toJSON(list(x=unbox(1),y=c(1,2)))
{"x":1,"y":[1,2]} 
> jsonlite::toJSON(list(x=unbox(1),y=unbox(c(1,2)))) # expect error here.
Error: Tried to unbox a vector of length 2
```

Comment: _"It is usually safer to avoid this and instead use the `unbox()` function to unbox individual elements. An exception is that objects of class AsIs (i.e. wrapped in I()) are not automatically unboxed. This is a way to mark single values as length-1 arrays."_

Comment: What if my list is R object, and these elements I want to unbox are 4 levels deep in the list?